# Pandas easy API to find out all inf or nan cells?

Tags: pandas

I had search stackoverflow about this, all are so complex.

I want to output the row and column info about all cells that is `inf` or `NaN`.

Comment: How should looks expected ouput?

Comment: @jezrael Output a dataframe only contains cells is `inf` or `NaN`, in other words, a sub dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `np.inf` to missing values and test them by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and last test at least one `True` by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) passed to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for `SubDataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,np.inf],
         'C':[7,np.nan,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[np.inf,3,6,9,2,np.nan],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})
print (df)
   A    B    C  D    E  F
0  a  4.0  7.0  1  inf  a
1  b  5.0  NaN  3  3.0  a
2  c  4.0  9.0  5  6.0  a
3  d  5.0  4.0  7  9.0  b
4  e  5.0  2.0  1  2.0  b
5  f  inf  3.0  0  NaN  b

m = df.replace(np.inf, np.nan).isna()
print (m)
       A      B      C      D      E      F
0  False  False  False  False   True  False
1  False  False   True  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False  False
5  False   True  False  False   True  False
```

---

```
df = df.loc[m.any(axis=1), m.any()]
print (df)
     B    C    E
0  4.0  7.0  inf
1  5.0  NaN  3.0
5  inf  3.0  NaN
```

Or if need index and columns names in DataFrame use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Index.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_frame.html):

```
s = df.replace(np.inf, np.nan).stack(dropna=False)

df1 = s[s.isna()].index.to_frame(index=False)
print (df1)
   0  1
0  0  E
1  1  C
2  5  B
3  5  E
```